# 20.04 software updater failed to download repository information

Tags: updates, 20.04, repository

In Ubuntu 20.04 when I run the Software Updater, I get the this message:

> Failed to download repository information -- check internet connection

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, this is the result:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                   
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]  
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
                                         
E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 4h 0min 28s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

E: Release file for http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3h 26min 43s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

E: Release file for http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 3h 26min 15s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the following method worked for me. In Software Updater, I went to Settings -> Other Software. One of the boxes listed there was checked, it corresponded to software which I could not have previously installed. I unchecked this box and run Software Updater again. This time, message «Failed to download repository information»‎ did not appear.